# PostgreSQL stored procedure data parameter

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following stored procedure, which returns 0 results but if the run the query by itself it result lot of results. What am i missing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countStatistics(baselineDate Date) RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
    qty int;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO qty FROM statistics WHERE time_stamp = baselineDate;
    RETURN qty;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--Execute the function
SELECT countStatistics('2015-01-01 01:00:00') as qty;
```

return 0 results

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statistics WHERE time_stamp = '2015-01-01 01:00:00';
```

return 100+ results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're declaring your `baselineDate` parameter as a `date`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countStatistics(baselineDate Date)
```

but using it as a `timestamp`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO qty FROM statistics WHERE time_stamp = baselineDate;
```

You're getting an implicit cast so `countStatistics('2015-01-01 01:00:00')` will actually execute this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO qty FROM statistics WHERE time_stamp = '2015-01-01';
```

and, after the `date` is implicitly cast back to a `timestamp`, it will effectively be this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO qty FROM statistics WHERE time_stamp = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Try changing your function declaration to use a `timestamp`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countStatistics(baselineDate timestamp)
```